# How to secure an enpoint to prevent programatic calls from the client?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, api, client-side, end-points

We have a game that is built on the client side. People who get past a certain level are eligible to enter a raffle. This is done by sending a request to an endpoint from the client once they get past level N. But this is prone to someone figuring out this call from the network tab, and programatically sending the request. Skipping the game entirely. How do I secure this endpoint so only players who reach a certain level can call it?

Comment: You cannot. The rule is that security can only be server side. Client side can only handle ergonomics rules. If you really want to go that way, you will only be able to use *obfuscation* which is definitely not security but could meet your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Unless you have complete control of the endpoint (down to a hardware level), you cannot trust it, and you cannot prevent someone from being able to bypass any client-side controls. There are things you can do to make it harder (maybe the to point where it's not worth their time and effort), but you can't prevent them entirely.

You need to implement your security on the server-side.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I secure this endpoint so only players who reach a certain level can call it?

Authenticate the players, and make sure the endpoint will only allow calls from players who are authenticated and recorded as having completed all previous parts.

Comment: I like the idea of recording each level, but how would record that securely? let's say the are authenticated with a jwt. They could then grab this token, create a script to record the levels

Comment: @sam if you want to stop players from cheating, you have to store most of the game state on the server. So rather than a player sending a message saying "I completed this level" or "I'm here", they should be sending "I'm starting this level", "I took one step forward", "I fired my gun", etc. All the calculations about what happened and whether they won the game take place on the server.

Comment: @sam This is a trade off... to get 100% security you need a server-side game as Gh0stFish mentions. However your client and server could exchange some information to try to make it harder to fake solving the levels... your client can tell the server when it starts a given level and maybe send an "heartbeat" every X seconds that gives some information regarding the progress in the level and your server can try to validate if what you get makes sense (what info that could be 100% depends on the game and how it works...)